# Cannot pass javascript variables into ActionScript. Get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTextToFlash' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, forms, typeerror

I have an HTML Form and a SWF file on the same page. I want the user to enter some values in an html form, click send and have the values sent to the swf for populating (No Refresh of the page, and I would like to use AJAX/JSON but I cannot.) I cannot get this to work. At this point I just want to write the javascript variables or at least parse the JS Object onto the artboard of the swf. Once that works I can go far. It feels like the js and the swf/as3 just aren't communicating. I also think that I am not targeting the swf object correctly. Here is the code:

The HTML:

```
<article>
        <aside>
            <div class="box">
                <form id="submit2swf" name="submit2swf"> 
                    <label>Link 1:</label>
                    <input name="link1" value="www.google.com" />
                    <label>Link 2:</label>
                    <input name="link2" value="www.autotrader.com" />
                    <label>Link 3:</label>
                    <input name="link3" value="www.webgraphicsatlanta.com" />
                    <label>Give this a string:</label>
                    <textarea name="string" placeholder="Default string is empty variable..."></textarea>
                </form>
                <div id="send2swf" class="button">Send this data to the SWF</div>
            </div>
        </aside><aside>
            <div class="box">
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="300" height="300" id="dogs" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="dogs.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="dogs.swf" width="300" height="300">
                    <param name="movie" value="dogs.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>    
            </div>
        </aside>
    </article>
```

The AS3/SWF:

```
import flash.external.*;
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Hello from ActionScript");//It says hello
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendTextToFlash", getTextFromJavaScript);
function getTextFromJavaScript(urls):void {//Won't trigger this function
    trace('text: '+urls);
}
```

The JS:

```
function sendData(urls) {
    inputs = $('#submit2swf :input'),
    urls = {};
    inputs.each(function() {
        urls[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    SendDataToFlashMovie(urls);
}
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    /*if (window.document[movieName]){
        return window.document[movieName];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1){
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
            return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    else{*/
        return document.getElementById(movieName);
    //}
}   
function SendDataToFlashMovie(urls){
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("dogs");
    console.log(urls); //Logs my js object correctly
    console.log(flashMovie); //Logs my flash swf object correctly
    flashMovie.sendTextToFlash(urls); //Tells me that sendTextToFlash(urls) is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add my controller:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#send2swf').on('click',function(){
        sendData();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to find the Flash object on the page with the id "#dogs", but using "#" is a CSS selector.

So when you do window.document[movieName], it's not expecting a CSS selector, but just the ID itself. Try searching for the Flash object w/out the #.

Comment: I tested the different if's in the getFlashMovieObject and it is triggering if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)...

Comment: I changed the return to return document.getElementById(movieName); and it logs the correct object... but still says that the sendTextToFlash is undefined

Comment: Yeah, that might be true. Two things come to mind: 1) security settings in the Flash app prevent "script access", 2) you're trying to call the Flash function before the Flash app has a chance to add the function to the DOM (ie: use a `onload` or `onclick` event handler to call the Flash function).

Comment: I also tried adding an onClick to a temporary link and it still throws the same error

Comment: In the Flash code, make sure [ExternalInterface.available](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#available) is `true`. Also, the HTML you're using to embed the Flash app seems a little off. Usually you use an `<object>` tag for IE and an `<embed>` tag for the other browsers. It's been too long since I did this, but usually the object tag contains the embed tag. Or you can try using [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed Flash instead. Finally, try other browsers to see if they behave any differently.

Answer (score 0):

Wow so externalInterface does not like external JS files AT ALL... What a waste of 8 hours...

Here is the working code for those stuck:

The HTML/JS:

```
<article>
        <aside>
            <div class="box">
                <form id="submit2swf" name="submit2swf"> 
                    <label>Link 1:</label>
                    <input name="link1" value="www.google.com" />
                    <label>Link 2:</label>
                    <input name="link2" value="www.autotrader.com" />
                    <label>Link 3:</label>
                    <input name="link3" value="www.webgraphicsatlanta.com" />
                    <label>Give this a string:</label>
                    <textarea name="string" placeholder="Default string is empty variable..."></textarea>
                </form>
                <div id="send2swf" class="button">Send this data to the SWF</div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="sendData()">Home</a>
            </div>
        </aside><aside>
            <div class="box">
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="300" height="300" name="MyFlashWidget" id="MyFlashWidget" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="dogs.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="MyFlashWidget" data="dogs.swf" width="300" height="300">
                    <param name="movie" value="dogs.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>    
            </div>
        </aside>
    </article>
    <script>

        function sendData(urls) {
            inputs = $('#submit2swf :input'),
            urls = {};
            inputs.each(function() {
                urls[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });
            console.log(urls);
            return urls;
            //SendDataToFlashMovie(urls);
        }
        $(window).load(function(e) {
            $('#send2swf').on('click',function(){
                sendData();
                var flashMovie = window.document.MyFlashWidget;
                console.log(flashMovie);
                flashMovie.sendData();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The AS3:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function createText(){
    var value:Object = ExternalInterface.call("sendData");
    var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
    myTextBox.text = value.link1;    
    addChild(myTextBox); 
}
createText();
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendData", createText);
```